# Can't install phpunit globally Mac

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer globally using.

> `>composer global require phpunit/phpunit`

But for some reason I can't, since it's already installed somewhere else. But not with composer.

Can I uninstall phpunit and require it globally again?

Comment: is already installed? if you try to execute it via shell what happen? how is installed? via brew? if you launch `which phpunit` what print?

Comment: phpunit not found

Comment: verify you have launched from your home directory, and verify what return the command `ls .composer/vendor`

Comment: Ensure you have launch from the home directory and that no one composer project already exists with a local installation of phpunit

Comment: If it's already globally installed with `composer`, run `composer global remove phpunit/phpunit` first. However, I highly recommend to require `phpunit/phpunit` per project, rather than relying on it being globally installed. This also has the advantage that you can a) require different versions as needed (PHP version might be a constraint), and b) do not run into issues because of different versions installed in different environments (local development vs. CI environments).

Answer (score 4):

The official way for install globally is described [here in the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html).

As example for the current version:

> ```
> $ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.2.phar
> $ chmod +x phpunit-6.2.phar
> $ sudo mv phpunit-6.2.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
> $ phpunit --version
> ```

Otherwise you could follow [this article](https://akrabat.com/global-installation-of-php-tools-with-composer/) and launch, **from your home directory**:

> ```
> $ composer global require phpunit/phpunit
> $ export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
> $ which phpunit
> /Users/acme/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit
> ```

Hope this help

Comment: the problem is that I need to remove it first before I reinstall it.

Comment: I could run ./vendor/bin/phpunit from inside a project. But not globally